# jquery-ui autocomplete press enter is not working with ajax loaded form

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have autocomplete search is work fine when I hit the search button, but it does not work when I press Enter on my keyboard and I can not figure out where the problem is, it's jquery Ajax! or is it HTML! and I also tried autofocus but again it does not work. Can anyone direct me in the right direction?

The code look like this:

```
<div style="color:white;" class="form-group  is-empty">
    @Html.TextBox("OrderID", null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Order nr", @id = "search_term" })

    <span class="material-input"></span>
</div>
<button type="submit" onclick="SearchOrderList(0,$('#search_term').val())" class="btn btn-white btn-round btn-just-icon">
    <i class="material-icons">search</i><div class="ripple-container"></div>
</button>

$("#search_term").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Account/SearchAutoComplete",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            change: function (event, ui) {

                console.log("blala");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.text, value: item.text };
                }));

            }
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: have you put the autocomplete inside a `$(document).ready(function() {` ?

Comment: yes i did , but its not work :(

Comment: Does it reach your `SearchAutoComplete` action method? Have you added `jquery` and `jquery-ui` js references in your cshtml, in that order? And open browser's dev tools and check for errors.

Comment: Yes it Will reach to SearchAutoComplete with out No problem and Yes i was added jquery and jquery-ui references to my cshtml , but the an other problem i found my AutoSearchComplete is not working on mobile or tablet devices, I mean it will show my search bar and everything but it's not gonna show results or autosearchcomplete tab when I hit button or write something in text box but, on browser I don't have dat kind of problem

Comment: So it is working on your desktop browser but doesn't work only on mobile?

Comment: Yes, everything work fine on desktop besides the thing I was asked (Enter key),But on mobile no it's not working . Only thing i see on mobile it's just button & input field.. functionality no it's not working